# Powershell: How to Pipe Array of -Split Words into Command String

Tags: arrays, excel, powershell, split

New here. So forgive me ahead of time.

I have an Excel Spreadsheets which contains a list of Employee Names and their Job Titles, amongst other Employee data.

I wrote a Powershell Script that copies the cells with Employee Names and their Job Titles, then pastes to another spreadsheet. Which works fine.

Now I need to sperate the the Employee Names from their Job Titles. For Example:

PS > `($OrgChart2List.Cells.Item($Row, 1).Text)`

gives me:

```
Field Superintendent
Jan Doeadeer (TRIO) 12/7/15
PM-Oliver Twist
```

I have an array of title words I want to Split(filter out). Like this:

```
$AdminJobTitles =@(
"Field Superintendent",
"(TRIO)",
"PM-Oliver Twist"
)
```

I'm trying to filter out the all Symbols, Numbers and Title Words, to get just "Jan Doeadeer" with this:

```
$NewValue = (($OrgChart2List.Cells.Item($Row, 1).Text).split(" ")) -replace '[^A-Z]',''
$NewValue = $NewValue -split $AdminJobTitles
```

But I get

```
Cannot convert value ""PM-Oliver Twist"" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

So I tried using -join:

```
$NewValue = (($OrgChart2List.Cells.Item($Row, 1).Text).split(" ")) -replace '[^A-Z]',''
$NewValue = $NewValue -split ($AdminJobTitles -join ',')
```

But I get

```
Field
SuperintendentJan
Doeadeer
TRIO
PMOliver
Twist
```

Pulling my hair. What am I doing wrong? What many things am I doing wrong?

Comment: So the text from the original list, you want that filtered down to just `Jan Doeadeer (TRIO) 12/7/15`?

Comment: It might be helpful to split those one-liners into multiple statements, by storing intermediate results in variables. Makes it much easier to debug for you and helps people on SO to comprehend what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Mathias - I'm trying to get it to just the employee name. So "Jan Doeadeer". Zett42- Good Point! Just updated it!

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicating this use case. There are several ways to do this. Based on what you posted, working wrapped cell data, here is an example:

```
$RowCellData = @'
Field Superintendent
Jan Doeadeer (TRIO) 12/7/15
PM-Oliver Twist
'@ -Split "`n"

[regex]::Matches($($RowCellData [1]),'^[^\(]+\w').Value
# Results
<#
Jan Doeadeer
#>
```

***Explanation:
for your comment 'I'm trying to get it to just the employee name'***

Split on the line feed, no the other content, then take the array index to get the name and grab the string/words before the open parentheses.

Or this...

```
($RowData)[1] -replace '.(?<=\().*?(?=\s).*'
# Results
<#
Jan Doeadeer
#>
```

***Explanation:***
Positive lookbehind. Replace the left open parentheses and all strings/words that follow it.

Comment: Thank you postanote for your suggestion! Unfortunately, this would only work for this particular cell data. I have lots of others with different keywords, not exceeding more then 20 total. That's why ultimately I was searching for a way to pipe a long list of keywords I could -split from the Employee Name.

Comment: True, but that was the only sample data you posted. The techniques shown would still apply as options for you. You just need to tweak the regex to meet your string to match.